# How to dynamically remove a TableRow in android

Tags: java, android

In my program I dynamically add a TableRow that has 2 TextViews and a Button in each row. When the button is click I want to delete that row.

This is the code that I used to dynamically make the TableRows and add them to the TableLayout:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    ArrayList <Item> items = (ArrayList <Item>) bundle.getSerializable("array");
    TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl);




    for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++)
    {

        Item item = items.get(i);

        TextView name = new TextView(this);
        TextView price = new TextView(this);
        Button delete = new Button(this);
        delete.setText("Delete");
        delete.setOnClickListener(click);
        row = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         row.setLayoutParams(lp);

        name.setText(item.getName());
        price.setText(Double.toString(item.getPrice()));
        row.addView(name);
        row.addView(price);
        row.addView(delete);

        layout.addView(row, i);


    }





}
```

How do I implement the OnClickListener so that I can delete the corresponding row in which the delete button lies?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to get the row that the button is in to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as follows:

```
final TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

for(int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {

    Item item = items.get(i);

    final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);

    TextView name = new TextView(this);
    TextView price = new TextView(this);
    Button delete = new Button(this);
    delete.setText("Delete");
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layout.removeView(row);
        }
    });

    name.setText(item.getName());
    price.setText(Double.toString(item.getPrice()));
    row.addView(name);
    row.addView(price);
    row.addView(delete);

    layout.addView(row, i);
}
```

I have added an `onClickListener`, `row` and `layout` are final variables. This works!

Comment: String item = items.get(i);

Items is an arraylist with an item object I created, can that be stored in a String value?

Comment: Thank you! How do I give you rep? This was my first post. Usually I post in /r/learnprogramming on reddit!

Comment: Simply mark it answered. (Green Tick) So anyone else with the same problem can find help.

Comment: One last thing. This removes the tablerow from the view, but how would I delete the item from the ArrayList?

Comment: Make them `final` as follows: `final ArrayList <Item> items = ...` and `final Item item = items.get(i);`. Then inside `onClick`, after removing the row, do `items.remove(item)`

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`TableLayout` inherits from `ViewGroup`, so methods like `removeView(View view)`, `removeViewAt(int index)`, `removeAllViews()` and so on are all available to use as normal.

To set your onClickListener, something like:

```
Button delete = new Button(this);
delete.setText("Delete");
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Use getParent() to get the parent view which will be a LinearLayout
        // (A TableLayout is made up of LinearLayouts representing each row)
        // You can then use indexOfChild(View child) to get the index of the 
        // LinearLayout child in the TableLayout
    }
});
```

Comment: how would I go about getting the index of the row thats is going to be deleted?